# Rotate a dynamic form on a PDF file in every page

Tags: javascript, pdf

I need to implement a form into a PDF that permits me to have the "print date" when I print the file. On the paper

version of the file I want the print date while in the original PDF it must be hidden. To do that I want to add

JavaScript to the PDF.

My problem is that I can't rotate the text in all forms.

This is the procedure I follow on Acrobat 9 Professional:

1) I go to "Advanced->Document Processing-> Document JavaScript" and I add a JavaScript called "forms" as follow:

```
function forms()
{
var inch  = 72;

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {

    // create rectangle quads for field
    var aRect = this.getPageBox( {nPage: p} );
    aRect[0]  = 0.3*inch;
    aRect[1]  = 10.85*inch;
    aRect[2]  = aRect[0]+24;
    aRect[3]  = 0.85*inch;



    // now construct text field to fill with date information
    var f         = this.addField("PrintField","text",p,aRect);
    f.delay       = true;
    f.textSize    = 10;
    f.textFont    = font.HelvB;
    f.textColor   = color.black;
    f.alignment   = "center";
    f.readonly    = true;
    f.print       = true;
    f.hidden      = true;
    f.delay       = false;
    f.rotation    = 90;
}
}
forms()
```

2) After I go to "Advanced->Document Processing->Set Document Actions" and I set the Document action "Document Will

Print" as:

```
var f = this.getField("PrintField"); 
f.hidden = false; 
var d = new Date(); 
var year = d.getYear()+1900; 
var mins = d.getMinutes(); 
if (mins < 10) {mins = "0" + mins}; 
//if (d.getHours() >= 12) {mins = mins + " PM";} else {mins = mins + " AM"; } 
f.value = "DATA DI STAMPA "+ (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/"+ year + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + mins;
```

3) After I go to "Advanced->Document Processing->Set Document Actions" and I set the Document action "Document Did

Print" as:

```
var f = this.getField("PrintField");
f.value  = "";
f.hidden = true;
```

The output of the FIRST page is as shown in the following picture:

[image]

but the oter pages are like as:

[image]

Can you help me telling me what I do wrong?

Another thing: if I change the JavaScript code, save the pdf file and print the file it has two forms in every page:  the old one and the modified one! Why?

Many many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document JavaScripts are executed every time document is opened, but you not only define a function, you also run it. Therefore, after saving and opening again, you get 2 sets of fields.

I don't understand (maybe you neither), why you chose to create fields each time document opens and then hide them until printing. As I see it, possibilities are numerous, such as:

- you create them once using Acrobat UI tools;
- you run function, that creates them, only once through console in Acrobat;
- you create them (setting values) on "Will Print" and delete on "Did Print";
- you do it your way, as now, and delete fields on close;
- etc.

Now, about setting fields values (assuming you didn't choose third method above). Your "Will Print" function gets only a single field, on the first page, and sets its value. Others remain empty. You should have created fields with unique names (adding page number to a name is an obvious way) and then iterate over all of them with `get field` setting values, either re-creating names with the same algorithm or using `numFields` and `getNthFieldName`.

Comment: I did not understand the presence of more than one field but now that yoy explained how Acrobat works, I think I'll solve my problem! I let you know! THX